# Pyramid type figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem, I need to display three graphs in a pyramid structure in python, something like this:

```
   graph1
graph2 graph3
```

I'd like all three graphs to be of equal size, how do I do this?

Regards

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.pie(sizes_21,labels=labels,colors=colors,autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.title('$i_G(t)$ = %1.1f' %gini([i*len(X[1:])**(-1) for i in sizes_1]),y=1.08)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.figure(1)
```

I then have three different "sizes", sizes_1, sizes_21 and sizes_22. My plan was to do these pie plots three times.

Comment: How are the graphs formatted?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by formatted, but I basically do three pie.plots in python using some data

Comment: Then please show us the code that you use to plot the data.

Comment: are they text, images, are you using some drawing library....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way this can be achieved is by using matplotlibs `subplot2grid` function, the documentation can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Below is an example, the basics of which were found [here](https://pythonspot.com/en/matplotlib-pie-chart/).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['Python', 'C++', 'Ruby', 'Java']
sizes = [215, 130, 245, 210]
colors = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue']

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

#define the position of the axes where the pie charts will be plotted
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0),colspan=2) # setting colspan=2 will
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (1, 0))           # move top pie chart to the middle
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (1, 1))

#plot the pie charts
ax1.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140)
ax2.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140)
ax3.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140)

ax1.axis('equal')   #to enable to pie chart to be perfectly circular
ax2.axis('equal')
ax3.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]